# DataReader reads data of another DataReader

Tags: asp.net, exception, datareader

I am having trouble and getting headache with an asp.net application that one singular day, it mailed me a lot of exceptions (with global.asax) about that a data readed from a dataReader cannot be cast to a particular type. The strange problem here is the code that generated that excepcion never had been changed since it was working on production.

It could be possible in any scenario that a dataReader reads information of another dataReader in process? In the application the configuration and connection of a dataReader is done in a module function, and in a page calls that function and use that dataReader to read some info.
I didn't found anything like these problem.

If you need aditional info, just ask them.

Edit:

I'm posting now some code to recreate one of the scenario:

web project 1 "application":

```
Public Module funciones_asp
    Public Function rs_dr(ByVal query As String) As SqlDataReader
        Dim conexion As New SqlConnection("")
        Dim comando As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        comando.CommandTimeout = 0
        comando.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
        comando.CommandText = query
        comando.Connection = conexion
        conexion.Open()
        rs_dr = comando.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    End Function
End Module
Public Class fw_empresa
    Public Shared Sub rango_decimales(ByRef dec_unitario As Integer, ByRef dec_cantidad As Integer, ByRef dec_total As Integer)
        Dim query As String = "SELECT decimal_field_1, decimal_field_2, decimal_field_3 FROM configuracion_decimales"
        Using dr = rs_dr(query)
            If dr.Read() Then
                dec_unitario = dr.Item(0)
                dec_cantidad = dr.Item(1)
                dec_total = dr.Item(2)
            End If
        End Using
    End sub
End class
```

web project 2 "icomexvi":

```
Public Class ic_proceso_embarque_UI
    Inherits Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim DecimalesCantidad As Integer = 0
        Dim DecimalesValor As Integer = 0
        Dim DecimalesTotal As Integer = 0
        application.fw_empresa.rango_decimales(dec_unitario, dec_cantidad, dec_total)
    End Sub
End class
```

And the exception that throwed my that day was:

```
System.Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "1295|1|SIMPLE COLLECTION" to type 'Integer' is not valid. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(Object Value)
at application.fw_empresa.rango_decimales(Int32& dec_unitario, Int32& dec_cantidad, Int32& dec_total) in D:\Publicaciones\Comex\Produccion\application\application\App_Clases\clases\fw_empresa.dal.vb:line 161
at icomexvi.ic_proceso_embarque_UI.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Publicaciones\Comex\Produccion\application\icomexvi\proceso_embarque\principal.aspx.vb:line 4398
```

Notes:

- The fields of configuracion_decimales table are decimal fields, making me so strange that "1295|1|SIMPLE COLLECTION" could be read from that table.
- The function rs_dr is used a lot among all web project 2 "icomexvi" and web project 1 "application" for reading data.
- connection string omited here for security

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: How about posting some code? Wouldn't that be the easiest way to assess what is going on?

Comment: btw sounds like the issue is in the data that is coming from the database so sample date might help

Comment: If the code didn't change perhaps the database changed? Or you got some garbage data in your database.

Comment: ¿Did anyone have an idea of what happened?